# Outlook style events calendar for project based on MVC framework

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, calendar

I need large Calendar (not jQuery datepicker) with possibility to schedule events and show them on calendar. Calendar must support month/week/day views. It is very desirable for Calendar not to reload whole page when view changes (AJAX refresh). It must be easily customizable (CSS themes) and localizable. It should support drag & drop (for scheduled events). Such Calendar must be rendered on client side from JSON data snippet.

I know there are too many requirements to find Calendar that matches them all but all they are important.
I have found some free open source Calendar controls, but almost all are tightly tuned for ASP.NET but not MVC or have very "heavy" JavaScript codebase. Ideally i see it as jQuery extension but *not* server side ASP.NET control. The best ready-to-use solution I have found is FullCalendar by Adam Shaw (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/). It is jQuery plugin which source code I can change to fit my needs.

If you can suggest some better existing solutions I'll be very appreciative.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Other option:

- [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) (free)

It uses jQuery and the same event object type.  Fullcalendar supports a lot of hooks for customization too.  I've added color coding based on tags and other features rather easily with it.

Comment: FullCalendar looks very nice.  Going to use on a current project.

Comment: fullcalendar is great. used it on a big project, and no issues.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try our jquery calendar plugin. wdCalendar is a jquery based google calendar clone. It cover most google calendar features. http://www.web-delicious.com

```
* Day/week/month view provided.
* create/update/remove events by drag & drop.
* Easy way to integrate with database.
* All day event/more days event provided.
```

It's totally free(LGPL license)

Answer (score 1):

I use Web2Cal recently to represent a large set of data. The event/callback structure is different from most calendars. If you are a java developer like me (with lesser Javascript expertise) you will appreciate Web2Cal. It does not have the rather cryptic javascript syntaxes and code style. More event and function based. 
 Moreover, this is a more complete solution like Recurring etc. I would have been happier if the code was more open. I believe, their higher end version has the code available but not the lower versions.

But they made up for it with some good support. But I do like fullCalendar, but it is still not a full solution that was necessary for our product.

But very good to see more development and competition

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [E2CS calendar](http://e2cs.mm-mendez.com/?language=en), built in ExtJs, would meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks, this Calendar looks good. But I realized that I need some jQuery solution because I use jQuery as my primary JavaScript library. I do not want to include ExtJS into project.

Comment: I can understand that. I use Ext in conjunction with JQuery (through Ext's JQuery adapter), but some prefer to not have some of the overhead associated with the Ext library.

If you find another viable calendaring solution, please post about it here so that others may also benefit.