# have anyone seen a good asp.net mvc event month calendar

Tags: asp.net-mvc, events, calendar

I am migrated a site from asp to asp.net-mvc.

I was using a third party event calendar asp code.  does anyone know of a good asp.net mvc event calendar where i see a month view and it will show events in the date cells.

Comment: Look at my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806212/outlook-style-events-calendar-for-project-based-on-mvc-framework

Comment: In fact, any JQuery based stuff should be easy to use under ASP.NET MVC.
There are not (yet) many commecial components btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've skipped the serverside rendering and went directly for [jmonthcalendar](http://www.bytecyclist.com/projects/jmonthcalendar/)

It's quite easy to hookup the month-browsing to a controller action method.

You will also need to do a bit of tinkering with the [jquery-history](http://www.mikage.to/jquery/jquery_history.html) plugin (or something similar) to enable the browser back-button and links to specific months/dates.

And no, that is not exactly what you asked for, but that's what I ended up doing in your situation, and I'm quite happy with the result.

Comment: do you have any example code of the issues and workarounds that you ran into. is it posted anywhere

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't got any public available sample code. But I might be able to provide a snippet later today.

Answer (score 1):

There is one more solution - [dhtmlx scheduler for .Net MVC](http://scheduler-net.com), which is .Net adaptation of  dhtmlxScheduler library (arguable the best javascript event calendar)