# Creating a table dynamically, with multiple lines of text in each cell and each cell being clickable, in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, custom-cell, clickable, monthcalendar

I'm trying to design a calendar-type table that is built dynamically based on data from a separate database source.

This is an illustration of the basic design idea:

Here's an image:

[image: link to the image]

If an object was added that was referenced to a Saturday, another column would be added and if the one on Monday was removed, the column would disappear and vice versa.

The weekdays are column headers and the squares represents cells with some lines of information. Each cell in its whole should be clickable.

The entire table should show a single month only.

I'm thinking this might be very time consuming to implement, and will quite quickly become impossible to re-read and understand later on if it isn't designed right. So if anyone has a more simple way to implement a month-view of a calendar, with some lines of information stored in each cell, and a possibility to call `Server.Transfer()` on the click event of a cell, it would be just as ideal.

As far as I know, the [Calendar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar(v=vs.80).aspx) component doesn't support editing the contents of the cells in calendar, and other than that I don't really know which way would be the best way to go.

If I can improve the question in any way, please let me know.

Comment: Do a search on "Outlook style calendar" and you'll get quite a few leads. The Full Calendar link from [this answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/980558/1223642) stands out as a pretty good solution.

Comment: Just re-read your question, and realized you are wanting to not display empty columns. Is there some reason for that design? A calendar displaying days-of-week with some days randomly missing seems a less-intuitive interface for the end user.

Comment: Well, it's not a standard calendar, and only having occupied weekdays displayed is a feature request from the product owner. It's a bar, and what they want in the calendar is shifts - and the shifts most often fall on the same days. The only reason it isn't fixed to be static days is that they want to be able to add irregular shifts or change the opening days in the future.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. Just had to ask, since part of helping is making sure people start from the correct design.

Comment: I perfectly understand. I was also aware this idea for a component was a big project when I started it. And I was aware this would quickly become very messy - so I wanted some inputs. And part of writing this question was trying to avoid making it a too comprehensive explanation, since people usually only answer short, simple and reusable questions (which is good usually).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is not a Calendar, but rather a Scheduler control, which includes functionality to display a calendar view, add/edit "appointments" and provide events of what happens when you click them.

[This thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1532676.aspx/1) lists a lot of such Scheduler control that you can use, some of them free.

Here are some additional links that implement similar functionality:

- http://www.rekenwonder.com/aspnet/schedule.html
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7619/Databound-Schedule-Controls
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31766/DayPilot-Scheduler-Control-for-ASP-NET

I think reusing one of those components and spending some time to research them would be much less time consuming that implementing your own solution from scratch. If what you want falls into those common UI patterns supported by those controls, you'll be fine.

If, on the other hand what you want is not a common practice, you may rethink your approach.

Comment: Even though this is not the answer I needed, it is still _an answer_ and you were the only one providing one, so I'll mark your answer as the accepted one.