# Clickable Webcontrol, ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, web-controls

This is question is in relation to [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489552/creating-a-table-dynamically-with-multiple-lines-of-text-in-each-cell-and-each) in case you want some more background information.

My question is: Is it possible to make a cell in an asp.net Table clickable?

Or Is it at least possible to make a clickable WebControl (which should be possible to place in a ControlCollection), that is not a Button or a LinkButton, in ASP.NET?
And if not, is it possible to multiple lines of information into the button text?

I've tried adding other components to the button's ControlCollection (which I've seen working in the Windows Forms version of the [Button](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.aspx)), to see if I could render child components to a button, but without success:

```
private void ModifyTableCell(TableCell cell)
{
    //Create new button
    Button btnCell = new Button();
    btnCell.Click += (sender, args) =>
    {
        //Event for the button
    };

    //Create new Label
    Label lblCell = new Label();
    lblCell.Font.Bold = true;
    lblCell.Text = "This text won't appear";

    btnCell.Controls.Add(lblCell); //Attempt to add label to Button
    cell.Controls.Add(btnCell);
}
```

**EDIT**: I ended up just creating a multi-lined LinkButton for the entire cell.

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to make pretty much any control clickable by assigning an `onclick` attribute and leveraging the `__doPostBack` function.

```
ctrl.Attributes["onclick"] = string.Format("__doPostBack('{0}', '{1}');", ctrl.ClientID, "SomeArgument");
```

You could also use the `GetPostBackEventReference` method too. This option is actually safer, because it will register the `__doPostBack` function it doesn't already exist:

```
ctrl.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(ctrl, string.Empty);
```

Then, in the code-behind you can simply override the `RaisePostBackEvent` method:

```
protected override void RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler source, string eventArgument)
{
    base.RaisePostBackEvent(source, eventArgument);

    if (eventArgument == "SomeArgument") //using the argument
    {
        //do whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. Also the Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference method is an alternative to __doPostBack. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771097/raise-server-side-button-click-event-from-javascript-in-ajax-call/8771155#8771155

Comment: Since I won't be able to have a variable that points to dynamically-created controls in the if-check in the RaisePostBackEvent-method, unless I have to add them to a list first, I can't really see how this would work.
To clarify: What this does, is essentially add an onclick-attribute that pretends it's made in the aspx-file, which then gets converted and then when the the RaisePostBackEvent is called, this gets called. Or am I understanding this wrong?

Comment: Why can't you just use the argument for your conditions? See my updated answer.

Comment: Yeah I can, that didn't occur to me. But am I right about the essence of this solution? I'd like to understand what's going on.

Comment: This solution basically hijacks the JavaScript function used by every other control that's capable of posting back.

Comment: Posting back to the server I presume?
But do all WebControls have this function?

Comment: You should be safe using the `GetPostBackEventReference` method, because I think it registers the `__doPostBack` function if it doesn't already exist. It's a common function used by *most* controls that are capable of triggering a postback.

Comment: It seems to reload the page (do a postback) even on Labels - but I can't get the ´RaisePostBackEvent´ method to be called, except if I use buttons.

Comment: ctrl.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(ctrl, string.Empty);
 is a very smart method for using in codebehind eg. rowdatabound etc.. Voted

Answer (score 1):

You can add multiple lines to a asp.net button by using the string builder, something like:

```
System.Text.StringBuilder buttonText = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
buttonText.AppendLine("first line");
buttonText.AppendLine("second line");
btnMultiline.Text = buttonText.ToString;
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you imagine such a composite control would be rendered. Remember that each ASP.NET control in the end outputs HTML. You Button essentially outputs a

```
<input type="button">The button text</input>
```

If you want to place anything else inside the `<input>` tag, it must be HTML-compatible. I'm not sure the input tag allows other HTML inside.

If it is a LinkButton on the other hand, the generated HTML markup is an `<a href="">` tag. You can put anything there, even an image if you wish, which will become clickable.

I am not sure what is your full scenario, but what you're trying to do smells bad. I suggest that you either use a LinkButton or rethink your approach, just have in mind what the final output in HTML would be.

Comment: You can see the full scenario described in the link I posted in the first line of my question. And yup, the html rendering has also been a worry of mine. But I'd gladly do a more simple and flexible solution if I find one.

Answer (score 0):

In reading both of your posts, it looks like you want to be able to click on anything in the cell and have it post back as if the whole cell were a button?

If so, one of the fairly simple ways to do it is to build your cell content as you would if you were not trying to post back.  Then add a button with a style of `display:none;`.  You can then use client side scripting to capture the click event of the cell, and raise the click event of the button to cause a post back.

This allows you to create the cell content in any way you like, and the postback code and handlers are automatically generated for you.

Using JQuery you end up with something along the lines of this:

```
<head runat="server">
    <style>
        input.ClickableCellButton
        {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("td.ClickableCell").click(function (event) { $(event.target).children("input.ClickableCellButton").click() });
        });
    </script>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="ClickableCell">
                        Cell Contents<br />
                        on multiple lines
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass="ClickableCellButton"
                            OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want to achieve. But won't the lines you write ("Cell Contents<br /> on multiple lines") be created beside the button?

Comment: Because the button is styled with `display:none` it is invisible in the browser.  This means that from the user's perspective it does not exist, but our javascript can still see it and raise the events associated with it.  So in essence this turns the whole cell into a button.

Comment: I misunderstood your solution. I thought the button inside the cell was the one raising the click event. But since this is a dynamically created asp:Table, how do you use add the JQuery to achieve this?
I found the control.Style.Add() method for the styling.

Comment: The JQuery snip parses out to english as: When the document has finished loading, scan it to find all td elements with a class of ClickableCell. For each element found register a click event handler to execute this anonymous function. The handler function says: Get the target of the event (the td that was clicked), look inside the target for an input with a class of ClickableCellButton (the button control in the cell), raise the click event of the input that is located (calls the buttons prebuilt postback code).

Comment: By including the JQuery snip on the page, and assigning the correct class names to the appropriate controls as they are created, we make it so that the client side code will find the cells with content/buttons and handle relaying the click event from the td element to the invisible button. This gives you all of the post back functionality of the button (command arguments, etc) along with all of the formatting capability of a table cell (multi line, auto width, etc), without having to try to write your own postback code.

Comment: Ah okay I understand now. How about implementing this? I only know the option of using a Literal to add this - is there any better alternative (since my code is growing big and messy already)?

Comment: That is a big topic and worthy of its own question.  In short there are several ways to do it and which one is best suited depends on many factors including how much time you have for this aspect of the project and how likely you think you are to use this again in another project.  It is way to much to try and answer in a comment.

Comment: Yeah I understand. I think I'm figuring out how to do it anyway - and I don't have the time to make it reusable and flexible.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're using the undefined css-class "ClickableCell" only to identify it in the script?

Comment: Correct, JQuery can use CSS style selectors to find elements.  The class is there to identify which cells JQuery should apply the event handler to.  There is no style rule associated with the class in my example, though you could add one if it fits your use case.

Comment: It doesn't call the click method. Neither if I use __postback function as the top-answerer has posted instead. Note that I'm using an ´asp:Table´, and not a td - but I can see in the generated html code that the td's have the class="ClickableCell". Are you sure your script is a working script?

Comment: It is working if you have a valid reference to the JQuery library, my default template has a copy in a Scripts folder.  Try replacing the `src` path in the first script tag with this:  `http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js`

Answer (score -1):

> And if not, is it possible to multiple lines of information into the
>   button text?

For this particular case, you can accomplish this via CSS only; no need to extend Button:

```
<asp:button id="myMultilineButton" runat="server" style="width:60px; white-space: normal;" Text="Several lines of text" />
```

It will render as:

[image]