# make custom control clickable

Tags: c#, asp.net, onclick, event-handling, custom-controls

I want to be able to click anywhere on my compositeControl custom control and it to fir a click event. Is this possible?

I have a custom control which is a panel with a few images and labels in it. It is supposed to be a button but im not sure how to make the entire control clickable. Any ideas?

```
namespace CustomButton
{
    [ToolboxData("<{0}:CustButton runat=server></{0}:CustButton>")]
    public class CustomButton : CompositeControl
    {
        Panel buttonPnl = new Panel(); //Declare and Init here in case you need it for chanmging background color at code compile and not run time


        //will put everything in a table in ordser to space it
        Table buttonTbl = new Table();
        TableRow imgRow = new TableRow();
        TableRow mainTextRow = new TableRow();
        TableRow subTextRow = new TableRow();
        TableCell iconImgCell = new TableCell();
        TableCell errorImgCell = new TableCell();
        TableCell mainTextCell = new TableCell();
        TableCell subTextCell = new TableCell();
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image iconImg = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image errorImg = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
        Label mainTextLbl = new Label();
        Label subTextLbl = new Label();

   protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
    /*
     * This builds the button. 
     * Note this is hit everytime the button atributes ar echnaged so this overrides everything. 
     * If you want control over a attribute, dont have it set here.
     */
    Controls.Clear();

    //init controls
    buttonPnl.ID = "buttonPnl";

    iconImg.ID = "logoImg";
    iconImg.Width = Unit.Percentage(50);//100% of cell width
.
.
.
.
build the custom control...

}
```

then i expose some custom attributes....

How do i add a click event to the entire custom control? Do i do this on the calling web page code?

I have added a action attribute in an attempt to do this but no idea if this is what i have to do.

```
[Category("Action")]
[Description("do some clicking")]
public event EventHandler Click
{
    add
    {
        Events.AddHandler(ObjEvent, value);
    }

    remove
    {
        Events.RemoveHandler(ObjEvent, value);
    }

}
```

Comment: I guess you can add event to custom control 'public event EventName'..No?

Comment: Can you expand on this? This is what im trying to do so need more info, put an answer down if you know how i can do this via the c# server side code

Comment: I have advanced the cause a bit, i put a 'action' category attribute into my custom button of type EventHandler, but again, not sure how to call it, so far my attempts have failed.Updated question with this info.

Comment: anybody have any suggestions on making a fairly simple compositecontrol clickable?

Comment: Did you have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10500019/clickable-webcontrol-asp-net. Look at James Johnson's answer

Comment: As he says "This solution basically hijacks the JavaScript function used by every other control that's capable of posting back", I guess you can have a button in your control and use it's ability to postback to have a clickable composite control